# How can I programmatically find the scale, rotate, and translate values when using the MultiTouchBehavior in a Silverlight/WP7 app?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, multi-touch

Okay, this may seem like a really silly question but I'm not quite used to the Silverlight realm yet.  I'm working on a Silverlight / WP7 application that references the Multitouch.Behaviors.WP7 codeplex project (http://multitouch.codeplex.com/).

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
      <Image Source="Images/image.png"
           x:Name="MyImage" Width="120" 
           Canvas.Left="240" Canvas.Top="235">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <tb:MultiTouchBehavior
        AreFingersVisible="True" 
        IsDebugModeActive="True" 
        IsMockActive="True" 
        IsRotateEnabled="True" 
        IsScaleEnabled="True" 
        IsTranslateXEnabled="True" 
        IsTranslateYEnabled="True" 
        MaximumScale="100"  
        MinimumScale="0.5"/>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </Image>
```

Obviously, the user can drag the image around, rotate it, and scale it with the multitouch functionality.  How can I access the values for how the image has been scaled/rotated/translated programatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MultitouchBehavior uses a [CompositeTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform%28VS.95%29.aspx) as the RenderTransform for the object that it is associated with. So, you can use code similar to the following to access the transformed values:

```
var transform = this.MyImage.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
var currentScaleX = transform.ScaleX;
var angle = transform.Rotation;
var offsetX = transform.TranslateX;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Image.RenderTransform. 
See this post (particularly the GestureHelper section - http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/16/silverlight-toolkit-for-windows-phone-7-released.aspx).

```
<Image x:Name="GesturedImage" Source="dividbyzero.jpg" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       Width="450" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScaling" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
  </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

And then use DistanceRatio to get the value for translation:

```
private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
   ImageScaling.ScaleX = e.DistanceRatio;
   ImageScaling.ScaleY = e.DistanceRatio;
}
```

Comment: Hey How can I use Gesture Library in my windows 8 phone project?
If I add gesture library in my windows 8 phone project then it gives me error LongListSelector is also exists in Microsoft.Phone.Controls. ambiguous reference to a class LongListSelector any suggestions how  to do it?